# Using std::process::Command with windows_subsystem="windows" causes console flash/popup

Tags: rust

Ok, here is my situation:

I'm making a program with a GUI in rust and I don't want to show the console window to the user.

The easy solution for this is the flag (don't know if that's the actual name for those things) `#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]`. It works great, and the console is gone. Buuut.. The `std::process::Command` struct is unusable because it flashes a cmd window and doesn't actually run the command.

So if I have code like this, I won't be able to use it. (But I need it)

```rust
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]

use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    // GUI stuff that at some point uses the Command like below
    Command::new("runas").args(&["/user:MY-COMPANY\\Administrator", "/savecred", path]).spawn().expect("Couldnt start Installer");
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can hide the console window but still be able to use `Command`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via Windows process creation flags.

Import [`CommandExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/process/trait.CommandExt.html) on windows from the std library, then set `command.creation_flags(CREATE_NO_WINDOW)`

Here's a small example of it

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::os::windows::process::CommandExt;

// Constant can be found in `winapi` or `windows` crates as well
//
// List of all process creation flags:
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags
const CREATE_NO_WINDOW: u32 = 0x08000000; // Or `134217728u32`

let mut command = Command::new("your-program");
command.creation_flags(CREATE_NO_WINDOW);
```

*I would like to correct something though*
It does actually run the command. It just also flashes the window while doing it. But of course, with the solution above, window flashing is now gone

Here's a list of all of the [process creation flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags)

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround for this issue is conhost.
You can use Command::new("conhost").arg("YourCommand")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).